# Draggable div in Dropzone.js after uploading photos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dropzone.js

EDIT: Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/9d3sok4v/2/

I created drag & drop and upload photos using dropzone.js plugin (http://www.dropzonejs.com) and php this is working normally but I want to add it draggable feature to the photos after upload and when I drag it could save its position.
My index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>   
    <title>Collager</title>
    <!-- 1 -->
    <link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


    <!-- 2 -->
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- 3 -->
   <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
   $( function() {
    $( ".dz-complete" ).draggable();
   } );
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a div of the photo which dropzone.js adds automatically after photo upload:

But dragging does not work after uploading. What is incorrect in this script?

Comment: Looking like what?

Comment: I edited it....